# check before inserting data is already existed or not

Tags: php, mysql

When i click first time inserting new data second time click that time it is not checking

```
function post($payload)
{   
    $stmt = $this->db->prepareQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE emailId= ? or phone= ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $payload->email, $payload->phone);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    while ($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        if($rows['emailId']!=$payload->email || $rows['phone']!=$payload->phone)
        {           
            $stmt = $this->db->prepareQuery("insert into user(emailId,phone,name,city,category_id,password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param('ssssds', $payload->email, $payload->phone, $payload->name, $payload->city, $payload->categ, $payload->pwd);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
            $this->db->commit();
            return $payload;            
        }
        else
        {
            $stmt->close();
            echo "Already existed"; 

            return $payload;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your question is not well formated

Comment: there is clearly something wrong with the logic here, because you are doing the same validation you are doing in where clause also again in php. how can you find something none existing from the list you are selecting?

Comment: I have no idea what your actual issue is. Please edit your question to include a proper explanation of your issue, expected result and your current result.

Comment: Also: `$this->db->commit();`, are you using transactions?

Comment: If your first query returns two rows as result (one for an email match and one for a phone number match), your code would run the insert twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking for the record like you know its going to be in the first row. How about introduce another variable say `$duplicate`

```
     $duplicate = false;
 while ($rows=$result->fetch_assoc()) 
 {
    if($rows['emailId']==$payload->email || $rows['phone']==$payload->phone)
    {           
        $duplicate = true;
        break;          
    }


  }

 if(!$duplicate){
   $stmt = $this->db->prepareQuery("insert into 
   user(emailId,phone,name,city,category_id,password) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
   $stmt->bind_param('ssssds', $payload->email, $payload->phone, $payload->name, 
   $payload->city, $payload->categ, $payload->pwd);
   $stmt->execute();
   $stmt->close();
   }
  else{
    echo "Duplicate";
  }
```